# Safari on iPad rendering background-color as a border around background-image

Tags: ipad, safari, rendering

This bug has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225558/1072343), but I haven't found a solution to it yet.

There are small lines on the top and bottom of my background image that appears to be the background color.  Both the background image height and container height are the same (29px), and the image is not transparent, but rather with a white background.  There isn't a border at all on the container, so this leaves me a bit stumped.  This looks fine in Safari on a Mac, but shows the above issue on iPad.

html:

```
<a class="help" href="#">Help</a>
```

css:

```
.help {
color: #fff;
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
background-image: url(../img/help.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #ee3224;
height: 29px;
line-height: 29px;
padding: 0 10px 0 26px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, It appears to be a difference between the way IPad safari calculates img size and it's container block size.

This is discussed more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6324025/1210282

The solution being to add an outline of 1px to your image to stop the background bleeding through

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this.

It's quite simple, just use:

```
background-clip: content-box;
background-size: cover;
```

where the background-color and background-image is set.

Comment: After trying over a dozen suggestions, this is the one that finally worked for me. Part of my problem was that I needed overflow:hidden on that div and the other suggestions did work if I changed it to visible. Anyway, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since I have padding on the box where this bug is happening, what did the trick for me is:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```