# How Can I Fix or Work Around SubPixel Handling on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, subpixel

**Setup:**  I am developing a PhoneGap/Cordova app for iOS and Android using jQuery Mobile.  The app requires a calendar which I am creating myself due to the fact that an exhaustive search of plugins didn't yield any results that satisfied all my needs. I am using seven div's - one for each day of the week - which are all `float:left`'d and each is set to `width:14.28571428571429%` as this is 1/7 of 100%.  I should mention that the calendar div container is set to `width: 100%`. Chrome developer tools also confirms that the container (id="calendar") is using 100% of the width real estate.

**Problem:** Everything looks and works great on the desktop, however once I start testing on my iPhone or iPad, a small margin (about 2%) appears to the right of the calendar.

**Supporting Details:** I have done quite a bit of research on this, and it appears that this is due to subpixel rendering.  I read about [Subpixel Rendering on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) and found [this two year old article](http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/) regarding the way different browsers handle fractions of pixels.  It seems to me that 0.28[…]% is being chopped off in mobile Safari. 
**The problem is, I don't know how to fix it.**  What confuses me even further, is that this appears to be a *webkit* issue, but the calendar renders just fine in desktop Chrome.

**Code:**

```
<div id="calendar">

    <div class="cal-week"> 

        <a href="javascript:monthPrev();">
            <div class="day day-inactive">28</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:monthPrev();">
            <div class="day day-inactive">29</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:monthPrev();">
            <div class="day day-inactive">30</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:monthPrev();">
            <div class="day day-inactive">31</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:selectDate(11,01,2012);">
            <div class="day">1</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:selectDate(11,02,2012);">
            <div class="day">2</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:selectDate(11,03,2012);">
            <div class="day">3</div>
        </a>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- fun fact: this is the first week of November, 2012 -->

    </div>

[&hellip;]

</div><!-- /calendar -->
```

Comment: This weekend if I can find the time I'll try to set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I have set up a JSFiddle to illustrate the issues I am having:  [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPDyY/7/)

When viewed via desktop, everything looks fine.  When viewed on iOS, notice that there is about 2% margin on the right-hand side of the row.

Comment: I was wrong - this same issue is occuring on desktop Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles on this:

After much (painful) searching through Webkit documentation, improper SubPixel handling is a well documented bug and needs to be fixed to make these types of issues go away permanently.  The only sure work-around I can find is a negative pixel margin fix.  [This qusetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832869/single-sub-pixel-misalignment-of-divs-on-ipad-and-iphone-safari) goes into some good detail on the matter.

In regards to my particular issue with seven columns, a negative pixel on each of the seven columns was creating a margin on the right-hand side of the screen.  What fixed me was the idea of only applying the negative margins to *every other* column.  So now columns 0, 2, 4, and 6 all have a `margin-left: -1px` and the other three do not.  It works for now, let's hope they get to addressing this issue sooner rather than later.

Cheers.

Comment: I should mention, this breaks rendering on non-Webkit browsers.  Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a terrible time with something similar in Firefox, so maybe you can fit my fix to fit your need.

My problem is/was that I need to calculate screen width during a changePage, which on Firefox sometimes results in the scrollbar being substracted in the width calculation, so if I need width 1000px I'm getting 983px (sans 17px scrollbar).

It took forever to console the wrong value returned by Javascript. I'm now using this to fix:

```
wrapWidth = document.body.clientWidth,
// FIREFOX SCROLLBAR WIDTH FIX
// When caluclating the width of the screen Firefox includes 
// the scrollbar width although the page height is less 
// than available screen height. 
// Therefore page width is off by the toolbar width (17px).
// browser window: window.innerWidth  ~ e.g. 924
// wrapper page: document.body.clientWidth ~ e.g. 907

// if the page height is smaller than screen height, correct by 17px. 
fireFoxCorrection = ( window.innerWidth !== wrapWidth && wrap.height() <= window.innerHeight ) ? window.innerWidth-wrapWidth : 0,
```

This gives me 17px when the error occurs and 0 when it doesn't, so I can safely do

```
element_width = calculatedWidth + fireFoxCorrection
```

How about trying if you can pin the down the correction in your setup using `window.innerWidth` and `document.body.clientWidth`. If you could extract the difference, you could divide it by elements and add this as to the width of each element.

Comment: Thanks, @frequent.  Unfortunately testing I've determined that window.innerWidth == document.body.clientWidth.  These values are being reported as equal in my Chrome browser (desktop), as well as iPhone and iPad.