# How to remove space between div content and border?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I have `div` inside another `div`. If I have a border in the outer `div` I got a space in Microsoft Edge browser in some scales (100% or 125%). I think it's a rounding bug, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

**html:**

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```css
.outer {
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.inner {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EvgeniiMalikov/4bbx9p5w/

As you can see there is black background visible between outer and inner div. If you don't see it try to change scale.

**UPDATE:** the gap really appears not between div elements, it's inside inner div close to its border. Discovered it by adding outline to inner div.

**example screenshot**

[image: example screenshot]

**example screenshot with border and outline**
(gap between border and outline)
[image: example with outline]

```
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid lime;
outline: 1px solid lime;
```

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: Background of outer div should not be visible between outer div and its content. I drawing pvc window blocks and I have multiple inner divs and outer to share one big background image. Background should be visible only inside inner divs.

Comment: This is due to sub-pixel rendering problem. See this thread (and maybe one of the several tricks in the answers there might help you) -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832869/single-sub-pixel-misalignment-of-divs-on-ipad-and-iphone-safari

Comment: Can you post a small screenshot of what you're seeing, sharing also the current zoom-level of the viewport? Also, an example of what you'd like to achieve, as we may be able to help you find an alternative approach.

Comment: Can you not remove the outer/inner div and just stick with one? If it's a width (percent/px) issue then just set `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: It is IE Edge specific case of sub-pixel rendering problem.
Screenshot 2 with captured with border box.

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov Can you show us what effect you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @Sampson background shouldn't be visible thru inner element

Answer (score 1):

the border 1px is adding to the width 300px. you need to remove 1px from the width

```
.outer{background-color: black; float: left; border: 1px solid white}
.inner{width: 299px; height: 300px; background-color: yellow}
```

Here is the screenshot from Microsoft Edge [image]

Comment: I know it, but I need a border

Comment: where do you think I should add 1px?